# What causes skating feet in Unity (but not in mixamo or Autodesk FBX review)?

Tags: unity, animation

I have uploaded a model to mixamo.com.
In mixamo, I've applied an animation, and in the mixamo preview window, the feet are perfectly stable, they don't skate at all.

I have downloaded the resulting fbx animation together with the skin, and I have opened it up in Autodesk FBX review.

In Autodesk FBX review, the feet are also perfectly stable.

I have then imported the fbx in Unity without changing anything.

In the animation preview window, the feet are skating.

Why is that so, and how do I get rid of it?

Comment: Please provide screenshots of your model import settings, that way we will have more information to work with. 

Comment: @eLTomis I have not applied / changed anything, I just imported it into Unity. Should I provide them anyways?

Comment: oh, if nothing is changed, then no - not neccessary. Just edit your question and mention that you kept default import settings. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that the skating feet were caused by the option "Anim. Compression: Keyframe Reduction" in the Unity Animation tab.

Once I set Anim. Compression to "Off", the skating feet were gone.

[image]